# problemas con laravel 10 no genera session

Tags: php, laravel

Hola estoy tratando de crear un login basico en laravel basicamente todo el proceso se realiza correctamente. Pero por alguna razon la session no se genera correctamente. Eh comprobado que la autentificacion se hace correctamente. Lo que no funciona es la generacion de sesion eh intentado de todo pero no logro dar con alguna solución.

LoginController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests\LoginRequest;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;

class LoginController extends Controller
{


    public function index()
    {
        if (Auth::check()) {
            return redirect('/admin/dashboard');
        }
        return view('login');
    }

    public function login(Request $request)
    {

        $credentials = $request->validate([
            'username' => ['required'],
            'password' => ['required'],
        ]);

        if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
            $request->session()->regenerate();
            //dd(auth()->user()->name);
            return redirect()->intended('/admin/dashboard');
        }

        return redirect()->to('/login')->withErrors('usuario o pass incorrecto');
    }
}
```

rutas

```
Route::get('/login', [LoginController::class, 'index']);
Route::post('/login', [LoginController::class, 'login']);
//dashboard
Route::get('/admin/dashboard', [DashboardController::class, 'index']);
```

User model

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens;
use Spatie\Permission\Traits\HasRoles;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasApiTokens, HasFactory, Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'username',
        'email',
        'password',
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
    ];


    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

    //metodo encriptar pass al registrar

    public function setPasswordAttribute($value)
    {
        $this->attributes['password'] = bcrypt($value);
    }
}
```

auth.php

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Authentication Defaults
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option controls the default authentication "guard" and password
    | reset options for your application. You may change these defaults
    | as required, but they're a perfect start for most applications.
    |
    */

    'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'web',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Authentication Guards
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Next, you may define every authentication guard for your application.
    | Of course, a great default configuration has been defined for you
    | here which uses session storage and the Eloquent user provider.
    |
    | All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
    | users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
    | mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
    |
    | Supported: "session"
    |
    */

    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | User Providers
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
    | users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
    | mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
    |
    | If you have multiple user tables or models you may configure multiple
    | sources which represent each model / table. These sources may then
    | be assigned to any extra authentication guards you have defined.
    |
    | Supported: "database", "eloquent"
    |
    */

    'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\User::class,
        ],

        // 'users' => [
        //     'driver' => 'database',
        //     'table' => 'users',
        // ],
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Resetting Passwords
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | You may specify multiple password reset configurations if you have more
    | than one user table or model in the application and you want to have
    | separate password reset settings based on the specific user types.
    |
    | The expiry time is the number of minutes that each reset token will be
    | considered valid. This security feature keeps tokens short-lived so
    | they have less time to be guessed. You may change this as needed.
    |
    | The throttle setting is the number of seconds a user must wait before
    | generating more password reset tokens. This prevents the user from
    | quickly generating a very large amount of password reset tokens.
    |
    */

    'passwords' => [
        'users' => [
            'provider' => 'users',
            'table' => 'password_reset_tokens',
            'expire' => 60,
            'throttle' => 60,
        ],
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Password Confirmation Timeout
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may define the amount of seconds before a password confirmation
    | times out and the user is prompted to re-enter their password via the
    | confirmation screen. By default, the timeout lasts for three hours.
    |
    */

    'password_timeout' => 10800,

];
```

La autentificacion funciona ya que al hacer
`dd(auth()->user()->name);`
me trae los datos del usuario logueado. Sin embargo la sesion es la que no se genera. Alguna ayuda porfavor que no se que mas hacer.